# Sorting a Sitecore query used to populate a droplink

Tags: content-editor, sitecore-query, fieldtype

We have a query that's populated a droplink that displays photo items.  It's grabbing these items from multiple locations, so the query is concatenating those subparts of the query.  I'm wondering if there's any way to sort the entire resultset so that users see an alphabetized list of photo items based on their name or title field rather than a list based on groupings of where the items lie in the content tree?  Here is the query:

```
query:/sitecore/content/Orgs/All Orgs//*[@@templateid='{55A41A27-A674-4A04-9716-8E5CB8786A85}']|../../../../../../../*[@@templateid='{9CB667FA-78F1-4EEB-9344-030E6B0AB1B7}']/News/Photos[@@id!='{4AF2C05E-BEC8-4DE0-BFBE-1D536CCA1A62}']//*[@@templateid='{55A41A27-A674-4A04-9716-8E5CB8786A85}']|../../../../../Photos[@@id!='{4AF2C05E-BEC8-4DE0-BFBE-1D536CCA1A62}']//*[@@templateid='{55A41A27-A674-4A04-9716-8E5CB8786A85}']
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to sort after combining the results out of the box. The query is sorted in hierarchical order.

Comment: It is not supported. You can create your custom field inherited from droplink and sort resultset in backend.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like basic functionality that one would expect to have, it's unfortunate you have to jump through hoops for basic sorting...